# $\vartheta(2x)<\vartheta(x)+x\log(4)$ implies $\vartheta(x)<x\log(4)$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, induction

If p is a prime and $n<p\leq 2n$ then $p|{2n\choose n}$. Therefore

$$\prod_{n<p\leq 2n} p|{2n\choose n}$$

$$\prod_{n<p\leq 2n} p\leq {2n\choose n}<4^n$$

$$\sum_{n<p\leq 2n} \log(p)<n\log(4).$$

And Chebyschev's first function is defined as

$$\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} \log(p)$$

so we can restate that as

$$\vartheta(2x)<x\log(4)+\vartheta(x).$$

And we can sum that for $x=1,2,4,\dots 2^{n-1}$ to obtain

$$\vartheta(2^n)<2^n\log(4)$$

But then how do we adapt that to obtain

$$\vartheta(x)<x\log(4)$$

for all x?

I know that that is true because the prime number theorem is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\vartheta(x)}x=1$, but I wanted an elementary proof of this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove the result for all $x\in(2^n,2^{n+1}]$ by induction on $n$. The base case (of $n=1$, say) holds by inspection.

Now, assume
$$\vartheta(x)<x\log 4\text{ for }2^{n-1}<x\leq 2^n.$$
Then, for $2^n<x\leq 2^{n+1}$,
$$\vartheta(x)<\frac x2\log 4+\vartheta\left(\frac x2\right)<\frac x2\log 4+\frac x2\log 4=x\log 4,$$
where we have applied our inductive hypothesis in the second inequality.

Comment: Here you're using the inequality $\vartheta(2x)-\vartheta(x)<x\log(4)$ for real $x$, right? I managed to prove it when $n\leq x\leq n+\frac 12$ for an integer n, but not for $n+\frac 12<x<n+1$. How do you do that?

Comment: @Derivative Oh, that's a very good point. I think it should follow from the bound $\binom{2n+1}n<2^{2n+1}$, which can be proved similarly to the bound you're using by noticing that $\binom{2n+1}n=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$.

Comment: I tried that, but it runs into trouble when n+1 is prime. At least I didn't manage to prove it.